# Ubuntu command line email tool for server

Tags: email

I started writing some scripts that backup my log files. Whenever an error is found in the log file, I want to send off an email to myself. However, I want to make sure that my server is not compromised as I've heard that having smtp/mail installed opens up new options for hackers.

Is there a tool that does not receive emails, but is only able to send them? Also, what security considerations would I need to take when installing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I want to make sure that my server is not compromised as I've heard that having smtp/mail installed opens up new options for hackers

*Any* service can "open up new options for hackers" if *it's poorly written.* But for mail, both Postfix or Exim4 are very secure.

(In general, you'll be fine as long as you don't use a ten-year-old Sendmail. Current versions are secure, but I would recommend staying away from Sendmail anyway – the configuration file isn't exactly human-readable.)

> Is there a tool that does not receive emails, but is only able to send them?

Any MTA (Postfix, Exim4, Sendmail) can work this way – just configure it to listen on loopback addresses only (`::1` and `127.0.0.1`). You can even disable the SMTP compontent entirely – most Unix programs do not require it and send mail through `/usr/sbin/sendmail`<sup>1</sup>, making SMTP unnecessary.

It's really not necessary against "hackers", though. The worst you can get with a decent MTA is leaving it open for relaying – and the default configurations already take care of that.

Another option is `msmtp`, which doesn't even have full SMTP support – all it can do is relay mail through another mail server, such as Gmail's or your ISP's. But while it's useful for a personal computer, it doesn't really fit into a server environment.

---

<sup>1</sup> "`/usr/sbin/sendmail`" is a program that comes with *all* MTAs, while "Sendmail" is the name of a *specific* MTA.

Comment: May I suggest using a google.com email account to sent outgoing automated messages? That's how I have my servers set up, that way if anyone ever comprises my email for spam, I only lose a *very* replaceable email account and no blacklist. All you need to do is setup your favorite MTA to send through your google account. Also, OSSEC - google it.

Comment: @skub: Sounds very promising, which MTA are you using with gmail?

Comment: You can do it with either Exim or Postfix, but I think Exim is easier to configure. Here are the instructions for Exim and Gmail: http://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4

Comment: @skub: Just for the record, Exim on Debian/Ubuntu has a *very* different configuration system (M4-based) than it does on other distributions. It's not always "easier".

Comment: You're right, it could be harder to set up in other systems. It was just an assumption that the poster was using some flavor of *nix. The theory remains the same regardless of the system used. You could setup a smart host with authentication in any MTA - including exchange.

Comment: @skub: My experience is that it's *easier* without the Debconf layer...

Answer (score 2):

Sending mail from a shell script is fairly easy as long as you have a standard MTA installed (Postfix, Exim4, Sendmail, etc). Generally to send you can use the `mail` command with appropriate arguments, echoing your email content to the program. For example:

```
echo "Error occurred in script at `date`" | mail -s "Error running script" youremail@domain.com
```

the `-s` argument specifies the subject and you follow with the email recipient.

Another example

```
grep -i error /path/to/yourfile.log | mail -s "Errors from script execution" youremail@domain.com
```

Check `man mail` for more options.

Another option if you're running your script via cron, is to have cron automatically email the output from your script to you. Add the `MAILTO` option to your crontab as follows:

```
MAILTO=youremail@domain.com
```

and you'll receive an email with any output from stdout each time your script runs.

As for security, sending and receiving email are 2 completely different things. You can send email from your server without running a receiving mail server, simply don't run the smtp daemon or block access to incoming port 25 (SMTP) via a firewall if you don't need to receive email via this server.